# My textarea disturbing my other td elements within the table

Tags: html, css

This is the sample code:

```html
<table>
      <tr>
       <td>
         Distrubed td element number 1
       </td>
       <td>
         Distrubed td element number 2
       </td>
       <td>
         Distrubed td element number 3
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="3"> // sorry forgot to type
        <form method="post">
         <textarea>The one who causing disturbance</textarea>
          <button>Sample</button>
        </form>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

The problem is whenever I resizing the `textarea element` the said `td` elements are going to adjust too. Though my code does have not a `css` yet. I just want to know what is the cause of this. Either bug or the coding itself. Thank you !

Comment: Why do you need to use a `table`? Can you not use `div` tags instead

Comment: That's because if one `td` expands _all_ `td`'s in the column will also expand. That isn't a bug or an error, its how tables work. On a side note, the `td` that contains your `textarea` should have `colspan="3"` if it is the only element in the row as all rows must contain the same number of columns

Comment: It is easier for me, and most on my pages are built in tables

Comment: @Turnip, yeah sorry, forgot to type it on my question. But when I try to input a specific width on my `table` where the `textarea` can expand and does not affect the `table`, but the `td` elements still affected, So that how table works, no ?

Answer (score 0):

Better you specify **`cols`** for your text area. This will solve your issue.

e.g;

```
<textarea cols="20">The one who causing disturbance</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution but you could always remove the textarea/button element from the flow of the page by using `position: absolute;` on a `div` container. You were also missing a closing tag on td element 3.

The problem with this method is that, if there are other elements below the `textarea` and `button`, they will appear directly underneath. You can however solve this by placing an element with a fixed height to push content down past this area.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3txdqq74/2/)

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    Distrubed td element number 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Distrubed td element number 2
  </td>
  <td>
    Distrubed td element number 3
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"> // sorry forgot to type
    <form method="post">
      <div>
        <textarea>The one who causing disturbance</textarea>
        <button>Sample</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  position: absolute;
}
button {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's neither a bug nor problem in your coding. It's designed that way, If you increase width of one row it will increase width of table and other rows will be affected(will stretch themselves to adjust in table's width).

to see this in working add `max-width` to `td` having `textarea`

this will work until you specify any width

Note: adding `max-width` is only for explanation. it will block stretching but it is not a good solution as `text-area` may go beyond `td` and can cause problem to other elements in your page

Comment: Thanks, that's great help!